# Extracting only the body of email using Python

Tags: python, email

I am using Python to read the Enron email dataset. I have the emails in text files. I would like to read the text files and extract only the "Body" section of each email. I am not concerned about any other `FROM`, `TO`, `BCC`, `attachments`, `DATE`, etc. I only want the `BODY` section and would like to store it in a list. I tried to use the `get_payload()` function, but it still prints everything. How do I skip the other content and use only the Body section?

```
import email.parser
from email.parser import Parser

# Code to extract a particular section from raw emails.

parser = Parser()
text1 = open("path of the file", "r").read()
msg = email.message_from_string(text1)
email = parser.parsestr(text1)

if msg.is_multipart():
    for payload in msg.get_payload():
       print payload.get_payload()
else:
    print msg.get_payload()
```

One file may contain multiple emails. Sample emails.

```
docID:  1
segmentNumber:  0
Body:   I just checked with Carolyn on your invoicing for the conference.  She 
verified the 85K was processed.

##########################################################
docID:  2
segmentNumber:  0
Body:   null
##########################################################
docID:  3
segmentNumber:  0
Body:   In regard to the costs for the GAM conference, Karen told me the $ 6,695.97 
figure was inclusive of all the items for the conference.  However, after 
speaking with Shweta, I found out this is not the case.  The CDs are not 
included in this figure.  

The CD cost will be $2,011.50 + the cost of postage/handling (which is 
currently being tabulated).


##########################################################
docID:  3
segmentNumber:  1
Body:   
This is the original quote for this project and it did not include the 
postage. As soon as I have the details from the vendor, I'll forward those to 
you.
Please call me if you have any questions.
```

Comment: Hmm, what you show is **not** in email format... In an email, you have headers starting with a header name, then a blank line and the following is the body. In particular, there is nothing like *Body=* or *Body:*. This is a specific format and you should not try to use the email module but parse it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your files has the format specified in your example, this might work:

```
email_body_list = [ email.split('Body:')[-1] for email in file_content.split('##########################################################')]
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. But this does not let me differentiate between the different emails. Once i have the email_body_list, I have the text contained in the body section of the email in this one variable. But what if I now want to extract of the emails from this? This does not let me do that. Right? How do I solve that?

Comment: Your initial question was how to extract only the body of the emails in a list. This solves that problem. Would you like to store the whole emails in the list?

Comment: Yes, I would rather like to store each email in a list. So that I could extract a particular email at a later stage after processing it. Thanks for the earlier update though. That does bring the data together.